# Melt dataset based on two rows using R

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

I have a dataset with two rows as columns, I would like to melt the dataset in order to have just 6 columns (country , date, var1, var2, var3, var4). Below a sample code to understand. Thanks for the help.

```
# what i have
date_or <- c("2001 q1", "2001 q2", "2001 q3","2001 q4")

AT <- c("var1","1","2","3")
AT1 <- c("var2","1","2","3") #in the real dataset is the same name as column ("AT")
AT2 <- c("var3","1","2","3") #in the real dataset is the same name as column ("AT")
AT3 <- c("var4","1","2","3") #in the real dataset is the same name as column ("AT")
BE <- c("var1","1","2","3")
BE1 <- c("var2","1","2","3") #in the real dataset is the same name as column ("BE")
BE2 <- c("var3","1","2","3") #in the real dataset is the same name as column ("BE")
BE3 <- c("var4","1","2","3") #in the real dataset is the same name as column ("BE")

dt_or <- data.frame(date_or, AT, AT1, AT2, AT3)
head(dt_or)

# what I would like to obtain
date <- c("2001 q1", "2001 q2", "2001 q3","2001 q4"
          ,"2002 q1","2002 q2","2002 q3","2002 q4")

country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT",
             "BE","BE","BE","BE",
             "DE","DE","DE","DE",
             "ES","ES","ES","ES")

feature <- c("var1","var2", "var3", "var4"
             ,"var1","var2", "var3", "var4"
             ,"var1","var2", "var3", "var4"
             ,"var1","var2", "var3", "var4")

value <- c(seq(1,16,1)) # as for example

dt <- data.frame(date, country, feature, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the columns in long format which starts with `"AT"`, get the second-row values in a separate column (`feature`). We need to use some logic to get these values, in the example shared the values which we want in second column contain alphabets so we use that logic in `replace` to change them to `NA`.

Finally, we `fill` the missing values by the previous non-NA values and remove the rows with alphabets.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt_or %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('AT')) %>%
  mutate(feature = replace(value, !grepl('[A-Za-z]', value), NA)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(feature) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!grepl('[A-Za-z]', value)) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)


# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   date_or name  value feature
#   <chr>   <chr> <int> <chr>  
# 1 2001 q2 AT        1 var1   
# 2 2001 q2 AT1       1 var2   
# 3 2001 q2 AT2       1 var3   
# 4 2001 q2 AT3       1 var4   
# 5 2001 q3 AT        2 var1   
# 6 2001 q3 AT1       2 var2   
# 7 2001 q3 AT2       2 var3   
# 8 2001 q3 AT3       2 var4   
# 9 2001 q4 AT        3 var1   
#10 2001 q4 AT1       3 var2   
#11 2001 q4 AT2       3 var3   
#12 2001 q4 AT3       3 var4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dt_or)`), `melt` the data into 'long' format, grouped by 'variable', create the 'feature' column as the `first` element in 'value', and `filter` the rows where the 'value' `startsWith` 'var'

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dt_or), id.var = 'date_or')[,
   feature := first(value), .(variable)][!startsWith(value, 'var')][order(date_or)]
#    date_or variable value feature
# 1: 2001 q2       AT     1    var1
# 2: 2001 q2      AT1     1    var2
# 3: 2001 q2      AT2     1    var3
# 4: 2001 q2      AT3     1    var4
# 5: 2001 q3       AT     2    var1
# 6: 2001 q3      AT1     2    var2
# 7: 2001 q3      AT2     2    var3
# 8: 2001 q3      AT3     2    var4
# 9: 2001 q4       AT     3    var1
#10: 2001 q4      AT1     3    var2
#11: 2001 q4      AT2     3    var3
#12: 2001 q4      AT3     3    var4
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, use `pivot_longer` to reshape into 'long' format, grouped by 'name', create the 'feature' as `first` of 'value' and `filter` out the rows that are not needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt_or %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('AT')) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(feature = first(value)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    filter(!startsWith(as.character(value), 'var')) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   date_or name  value feature
#   <chr>   <chr> <int> <chr>  
# 1 2001 q2 AT        1 var1   
# 2 2001 q2 AT1       1 var2   
# 3 2001 q2 AT2       1 var3   
# 4 2001 q2 AT3       1 var4   
# 5 2001 q3 AT        2 var1   
# 6 2001 q3 AT1       2 var2   
# 7 2001 q3 AT2       2 var3   
# 8 2001 q3 AT3       2 var4   
# 9 2001 q4 AT        3 var1   
#10 2001 q4 AT1       3 var2   
#11 2001 q4 AT2       3 var3   
#12 2001 q4 AT3       3 var4
```